# How to automatically add a period in table of contents that is not there in the chapter heading in MSWord

Tags: microsoft-word, table-of-contents

I create chapter heading using the Heading1 style with a soft return between the chapter designation and the chapter title as shown:

[image]

I then add a toc somewhere else in the document and it looks like:

[image]

I need it to have a period between 'CHAPTER 1' and 'INTRODUCTION'. So it looks like:

[image]

I can do it manually but how can I get MSWord to do this automatically when the toc is inserted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is similar to the workaround in the other answer, but a bit less complicated.

Add a period after the chapter number in your headings. Then change the font properties of each period (either manually or, to save effort, by defining a character style) so that the font color is white and the font size is 1 pt. Although the first line of the heading will technically be off-center, the amount is so slight that no one is likely to notice. Still, when you style the period, you could also, for example, change the **Scale** setting in the **Font** dialog box to **1%** so that the character effectively takes no space at all.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you cannot. This is simply not part of Word's Table of Contents feature. The TOC is a *field* and the appearance is controlled, for the most part, by the TOC styles.

### Here is a Workaround

If all of your TOC level 1 are for these headings, you could

1. Put a space before Chapter in your numbering setup and
2. Add a space after it in each heading or a period that is formatted as white or a hyphen/dash that is formatted as white following, then
3. Modify your TOC 1 style to have a negative left-indent to offset the space placed at the beginning.

*If you use text (the period or hyphen/dash) formatted as white, unless on a colored background, it is invisible in the document but takes up space. The color is not picked up in the TOC and so shows up as black.*

*The space before in the TOC 1 style is to offset the space after when you center these in the body of your document. Adjust the indent setting to fit.*

Otherwise, you will need to manually edit your TOC in your final version. Any macro solution would also be directly editing the TOC after-the-fact. Such editing disappears whenever the TOC is updated.

**References:**

- [TOC Tips and Tricks](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/TOCTips.htm) by Word MVP Suzanne Barnhill
- The [part of my chapter on Complex Documents on the Table of Contents features](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/complex_documents.htm#Table%20of%20Contents)
- Specific information on the [effect of direct formatting](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/TOCTips.htm#DirectFormatting) in the heading on the appearance of the TOC - in Suzanne Barnhill's page
- Specific information in my page about the [effect of direct formatting](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/complex_documents.htm#Hyperlinks_and_Direct_Formatting) in a heading and how it shows up in the TOC.

SuperUser is an independent user-to-user support platform with no connection to Microsoft. You can use [the feedback mechanisms in Word](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/giving-feedback-on-microsoft-word-or-other/8df81a9b-84aa-46ef-bf88-24fb7fec96ba) to make suggestions or register complaints with Microsoft.